# Algebra generated by a countable set is also countable

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Let $M\subseteq\Omega$ be a countable set. I now want to show, that the Algebra $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $M$ is also countable.
Properties of an Algebra:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}\neq\emptyset
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
A,B\in\mathcal{A} \implies A\cup B \in \mathcal{A}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
A\in \mathcal{A} \implies A^{c}\in \mathcal{A}
\end{equation}

I tried to find a countable Algebra $\mathcal{B}$ with $M\subseteq \mathcal{B}$ so that I then can conclude $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ but that  didn't work.
Does anyone know how to go about this or is there maybe an easier way to proof this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "the Algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$" I think you meant "the algebra $\mathcal A$ generated by $M$".

Comment: Hey thank you that's right. Also I meant countable not finite sorry! I sometimes mix these terms up as english is not my first language.